# CSS - Is adding property names possible?

Tags: css, variables, properties

is it redefining (or adding) property names possible?
my idea is to do something like...

```
"new prop" name: my_transition{
   "add prop":{transition:value}
   "add prop":{-o-transition:value}
   "add prop":{--ms-transition:value}
   "add prop":{-webkit-transition:value}
}
```

With the aim of being evoked along the css as a cross-browser property for transitions

```
#my_div{
... 
    my_transition:.5s;
...
}
```

Comment: this is the purpose of SASS/LESS not CSS

Answer (score 0):

No, not with css.

I would suggest you look into SASS 
https://sass-lang.com/